# Can Cognitive-Moral Bio-Enhancement be considered as a valid category of enhancement?

Tags: bioethics

- Persson and Savulescu (2008) argue that cognitive enhancement and moral enhancement have separate aims. They argue that cognitive enhancement without moral enhancement is dangerous.
- John Harris (2011) argues that progress in Cognitive enhancement should not stop because progression in moral enhancement requires technological advancement.
- Carter and Gordon (2015) argue that cognitive and moral enhancement are more interconnected and not as independent as Savulescu and Persson claim in their 2008 paper.

`The question is whether one should define cognitive and moral enhancement separately? If not, is it justifiable to recategorize it as Cognitive-Moral Bio-enhancement?`

*One argument to support this latter view is that it agrees with both Persson and Savulescu (2008) and Carter and Gordon’s (2015) line of argument and also resolves Harris’ objection.*

### Reference

Carter JA and Gordon EC. (2015) On Cognitive and Moral Enhancement: A Reply to Savulescu and Persson. Bioethics 29: 153-161.

Harris J. (2011) MORAL ENHANCEMENT AND FREEDOM. Bioethics 25: 102-111.

Persson I and Savulescu J. (2008) The Perils of Cognitive Enhancement and the Urgent Imperative to Enhance the Moral Character of Humanity. Journal of Applied Philosophy 25: 162-177.

Comment: I have no answer, but the question chills my blood. Is there a known example of this 'moral enhancement' or is this going to be one of the benefits of 5G?

Comment: Tom Douglas has been mentioned in Persson and Savulescu (2008) who refers to the following findings-
- Oxytocin promoting trust.
- SSRI increasing co-operation/reducing aggression
- Ritalin reduces aggression in children with ADD (Attention Deficit Disorder)

The biological basis for some personality types which increase the likelihood of immoral behavior.
- Antisocial personality disorder may have a biological basis
- Criminality linked to MAO mutation in X chromosome when coupled with social deprivation. (Persson and Savulescu, 2008, pp. 172)

Comment: What has all this got to do with 'moral enhancement'. None of these dangerous drugs have any effect on a person's moral sensibilities. It's like saying a rope is a moral enhancement because we can use it to tie up burglars. The whole idea seems wild.

Comment: The idea is to improve moral dispositions such as altruism and conscientiousness through genetic means, TMS, and drugs. Some people are highly altruistic and others are often violent. CMBE does not enhance morality, it only increases the likelihood of acting morally through cognitive enhancement.

Comment: I see no examples here of anything that improves altruism and conscientiousness. All I see are drugs. If you really want to prevent aggression and anti-social behaviour then a good dose of arsenic should do the trick. Pardon my cynicism but I find this use of drugs for social engineering a very American idea that I hope will never be confused with moral enhancement.   .  .

Comment: It's perfectly okay @PeterJ the details could be found in the references.

Comment: I see no need for details.

Comment: what if the "singularity" were impossible for e.g. (maybe a bad one) carbon based life forms? would that change how you feel about humans? "all that is holy and mighty has bled to death under our knives"

Comment: there's just no need to rank people in that way, and if we were to then it would be for more than talking to oneself, for their economic status. owls are better at seeing in the dark. we don't rightfully consider them superior beings for it lol

Comment: long story short, don't come running to me when you suddenly lose the ability to empathize with (like?) yourself or think coherent thoughts.

Comment: @PeterJ Not even one American in the group of authors referenced here. Scotland, Australia, Sweden, and England (x2).

Comment: Could you add the specific definitions of the terms cognitive, moral, and enhancement? The current two answers use differing definitions. Also, im case the definition takes morals and cognition as completely unrelated concepts (unrelated as, say, morals and physical capability) do you think we had a moral enhancement of the order of our technological progress from the stone age onwards? if so, which form did it take?

Comment: @Bread - You're right to pick me up on this. My remark was misjudged. I forgot this madness is now global.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I am only trying to understand papers. According to moral enhancement, it is meant the enhancement of moral dispositions such as altruism and conscientiousness. These are very much interconnected with how the human cognition works. Hormones often affect people's moods and behaviors and therefore actions. I suppose Persson and Savulescu were indicating to these, rather than traditional form of enhancement such as education. The papers I mentioned are pretty intense just as this discussion is.

Comment: I believe the best and most reliable way to enhance cognition and morals in human beings is for everyone to be very selective about the *character* and *intelligence* of their mates / marital partners. Aka selective breeding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_breeding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognition is the acquisition and understanding of knowledge and morality is the interpretation of good and bad. Morality can be thought of as a type of cognition in that you acquire and interpret knowledge to make categorical judgments of good and bad. This type of cognition is just reliant on the experiences of suffering and pleasure. If you want to specify the type of cognition than yes "cognitive-moral bio-enhancement" works. Cognitive enhancement should be thought of as a generalization referring to the advancement of all types of cognition.

[Wikipedia Cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognition)

Answer (score 2):

The question is extremely badly worded

> The question is whether one should define cognitive and moral
>   enhancement separately? If not, is it justifiable to recategorize it meaning 
>   as Cognitive-Moral Bio-enhancement?

Presumably 'it' refers to what we see as cognitive or moral enhancement?

I see absolutely no reason to suppose that those that "hack" their brains as morally better persons, be that for altruistic (better science) or more personal reasons (pleasure). I mean, seriously, how insane do you have to be to even imagine that a piece of computer in your brain makes you an intrinsically better person, rather than of higher status?

So *surely* the answer is trivial. They should be defined as separate.

I suppose the lesson is that people can't escape their motivations as easily as they (we?) would want.

You also seem to have (in the question title) misunderstood 'category' to mean 'all there can be', which is kinda sad (there are separate, different, categories to anything we are asking about, else it is just a sort of substance). I guess people like talking to themselves.

Comment: given what we know about rats and pleasure, one may ask whether "cognitive-moral enhancement" is actually making us less insightful / creative / intelligent, rather than just enhancing our memory for things

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing my question. I really appreciate that.